# Inconsistent null value for ViewBag in MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I'm trying to create an MVC application that uses partial views to update comments where posted in a form following the example here http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/Content/ViewContent.aspx?et=4099&m=4094&ct=19603 at about the 24 minute mark. My code should match theirs exactly except for my using of "Id" instead of "ID", but I have checked for inconsistencies within my code for that and found none.

When I try to pass the `ViewBag.SessionId` into the parameter dictionary for the `_CommentForm` method of my `Comment` controller (upon submitting the form) I get an error message:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'sessionId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult _CommentForm(Int32)' in 'ConferenceExample.Controllers.CommentController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

Here is the code that resulted in this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("_Submit", "Comment", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <text>@ViewBag.SessionId</text>
    @Html.Action("_CommentForm", new { sessionId = ViewBag.SessionId })
}
```

When I force the ViewBag.SessionId to output as text before it is assigned to the `sessionId`, it prints out perfectly on the screen, but it gets to the line with the `@Html.Action()` and throws the error.

Likewise if I try to assign the value of `ViewBag.SessionId` to a variable and pass that in as the parameter I get a similar message:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("_Submit", "Comment", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <text>@ViewBag.SessionId</text>
    int foo = ViewBag.SessionId;
    @Html.Action("_CommentForm", new { sessionId = foo })
}
```

With an error message of:
    `Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type`

I'm not quite sure why `ViewBag.SessionId` has a value in some cases but not in others although I assume that is has something to do with it being a dynamic expression.

This is my first post, so let me know if there is anything I can do to improve my posts in the the future. Thanks!

Edit: (Included Controller)

The code above is in the `_GetForSession` View. The controller that calls it is below.

```
namespace ConferenceExample.Controllers
{
    public class CommentController : Controller
    {
        ConferenceContext context = new ConferenceContext();

        //Get list of all comments for a session
        public PartialViewResult _GetForSession(int sessionId)
        {
            ViewBag.SessionId = sessionId;
            //This kind of data access would be in the repo in production
            List<Comment> comments = context.Comments.Where(c => c.SessionId == sessionId).ToList();
            return PartialView("_GetForSession", comments);
        }

        //Create new comment submit form
        public PartialViewResult _CommentForm(int sessionId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sessionId.ToString());
            Comment comment = new Comment() { SessionId = sessionId };
            return PartialView("_CommentForm", comment);
        }

        //Accept new comment
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
        public PartialViewResult _Submit(Comment comment)
        {
            //In production you would make sure that the comment is valid before saving it
            context.Comments.Add(comment);
            context.SaveChanges();

            List<Comment> comments = context.Comments.Where(c => c.SessionId == 
                 comment.SessionId).ToList();

            return PartialView("_GetForSession", comments);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show any relevant code from your controller as well?

Answer (score 0):

The error due to ViewBag.SessionId is become null.In order to fix this issue change the parameter in the action as nullable

---

```
 public  PartialViewResult _CommentForm(int? sessionId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sessionId.ToString());
        Comment comment = new Comment() { SessionId = sessionId??0 };
        return PartialView("_CommentForm", comment);
    }
```